# Convert non-numeric tuples to numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to represent an adjacency matrix via a very large list of tuples. How would I represent this list in a numpy matrix or scipy.sparse matrix so as to use a package like igraph or networkx?

```
[('b', 'c'),
 ('b', 'a'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'b'),
 ('a', 'b'),
 ('a', 'c')]
```

I apologize if this is duplicate, but I can't find any documentation on how to convert non-numeric tuples into adjacency matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetworkX can have non-numeric nodes. If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use it in a networkx graph as easily as this:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ...])
```

Are you asking how to convert that to a `scipy.sparse` or `numpy` matrix? Or do you want it for use with graph and networkx?

Comment: That's awesome. My understanding was that I needed to convert my list to a `scipy.sparse` or a `numpy matrix` in order to use networkx. That would be amazing if I didn't. But I also want to convert it to something that  will be easily transferable to an `R dataframe` so I could use R as well. Two birds with one stone type of thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can convert your nodes into indices using `np.unique`:

```
>>> adj = [('b', 'c'),
...        ('b', 'a'),
...        ('c', 'd'),
...        ('c', 'a'),
...        ('c', 'b'),
...        ('a', 'b'),
...        ('a', 'c')]
>>> node_names, adj_idx = np.unique(adj, return_inverse=True)
>>> node_names
array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 
      dtype='|S1')
>>> adj_idx = adj_idx.reshape(-1, 2)
>>> adj_idx
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [2, 3],
       [2, 0],
       [2, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])
```

From this, you can construct your dense adjacency matrix as:

```
>>> adj_matrix = np.zeros((len(node_names),)*2)
>>> adj_matrix[adj_idx[:, 0], adj_idx[:, 1]] = 1
>>> adj_matrix
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Or in sparse format as:

```
>>> sps_adj_mat = sps.coo_matrix((np.ones(shape=(len(adj_idx),)),
...                               (adj_idx[:, 0], adj_idx[:, 1])),
...                              shape=(len(node_names),)*2)
>>> sps_adj_mat
<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 7 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
>>> sps_adj_mat.A
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```