# Create heatmap in python matplotlib with x and y labels from dict with {tuple:float} format

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, tuples, heatmap

I have a dict that consists of movie-title pairs as keys and a similarity score as values:

```
{('Source Code ', 'Hobo with a Shotgun '): 1.0, ('Adjustment Bureau, The ', 'Just Go with It '): 1.0, ('Limitless ', 'Arthur '): 1.0, ('Adjustment Bureau, The ', 'Kung Fu Panda 2 '): 1.0, ('Rise of the Planet of the Apes ', 'Scream 4 '): 1.0, ('Source Code ', 'Take Me Home Tonight '): 1.0, ('Midnight in Paris ', 'Take Me Home Tonight '): 1.0, ('Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2 ', 'Pina '): 1.0, ('Avengers, The ', 'Drive Angry '): 1.0, ('Limitless ', 'Super 8 '): 1.0, ('Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2 ', 'Arthur '): 1.0, ('Source Code ', 'Melancholia '): 0.6666666666666666, ('Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2 ', 'Jane Eyre '): 1.0, ('Avengers, The ', 'Arthur '): 0.6666666666666666, ('The Artist ', 'Attack the Block '): 1.0, ('Midnight in Paris ', 'Priest '): 1.0, ('Adjustment Bureau, The ', 'Hanna '): 1.0, ('The Artist ', 'Thor '): 1.0, ('The Artist ', 'Zeitgeist: Moving Forward '): 1.0, ('The Artist ', 'Green Hornet, The '): 1.0, ('X-Men: First Class ', 'Sanctum '): 1.0, ('Source Code ', 'Green Hornet, The '): 1.0, ('Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2 ', 'Something Borrowed '): 1.0, ('Adjustment Bureau, The ', 'Rio '): 1.0, ('Avengers, The ', 'Mechanic, The '): 1.0, ('Rise of the Planet of the Apes ', 'Something Borrowed '): 0.6666666666666666, ('Captain America: The First Avenger ', 'Attack the Block '): 0.6666666666666666, ('Avengers, The ', 'Zeitgeist: Moving Forward '): 1.0, ('Midnight in Paris ', 'Arthur '): 1.0, ('Source Code ', 'Arthur '): 1.0, ('Limitless ', 'Take Me Home Tonight '): 1.0, ('Midnight in Paris ', 'Win Win '): 1.0, ('X-Men: First Class ', 'Something Borrowed '): 1.0, ('Avengers, The ', 'Dilemma, The '): 1.0, ('X-Men: First Class ', 'Green Hornet, The '): 1.0, ('The Artist ', 'Just Go with It '): 1.0, ('Rise of the Planet of the Apes ', 'Arthur '): 1.0, ('Captain America: The First Avenger ', 'Lincoln Lawyer, The '): 1.0, ('X-Men: First Class ', 'Hobo with a Shotgun '): 1.0, ('Limitless ', 'Mechanic, The '): 0.6666666666666666, ('Captain America: The First Avenger ', 'Green Hornet, The '): 1.0, ('Captain America: The First Avenger ', 'Hangover Part II, The '): 1.0, ('X-Men: First Class ', 'Hanna '): 1.0, ('Rise of the Planet of the Apes ', 'Priest '): 1.0, ('Midnight in Paris ', 'I Am Number Four '): 1.0, ('Rise of the Planet of the Apes ', 'Tree of Life, The '): 1.0, ('Captain America: The First Avenger ', 'Hanna '): 1.0, ('Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2 ', 'Win Win '): 1.0, ('Limitless ', 'Drive Angry '): 0.6666666666666666, ('Adjustment Bureau, The ', 'Hangover Part II, The '): 1.0}
```

I would like to create a heatmap using matplotlib with the first movie in each key as y-labels, the second movie in each key as x-labels, and the similarity score as the z-axis.

So far, I have used the following as a guide ([Converting a dictionary of tuples into a numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446323/converting-a-dictionary-of-tuples-into-a-numpy-matrix?rq=1)) but it doesn't appear to be plotting the correct distribution (see figure).

[image]

The code I have at the moment that creates the numpy.ndarrray for the z-axis looks like this:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create a heatmap
sim_scores = np.array(dict_sim_scores.values())
movie_titles = np.array(dict_sim_scores.keys())
## return unique movie titles and indices of the input array
unq_titles, title_idx = np.unique(movie_titles, return_inverse=True)
title_idx = title_idx.reshape(-1,2)
n = len(unq_titles)
sim_matrix = np.zeros((n, n) ,dtype=sim_scores.dtype)
sim_matrix[title_idx[:,0], title_idx[: ,1]] = sim_scores

list_item =[]
list_other_item=[]
for i,key in enumerate(dict_sim_scores):

    list_item.append(str(key[0]))
    list_other_item.append(str(key[1]))

list_item = np.unique(list_item)
list_other_item = np.unique(list_other_item)


fig = plt.figure('Similarity Scores')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
cax = ax.matshow(sim_matrix, interpolation='nearest')
fig.colorbar(cax)
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(list_item)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(list_other_item)))
#ax.set_xticklabels(list_item,rotation=40,fontsize='x-small',ha='right')
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax.set_xticklabels(list_item,rotation=40,fontsize='x-small')
ax.set_yticklabels(list_other_item,fontsize='x-small') 
plt.show()
```

Any ideas on how to create this kind of figure?

Comment: Can you give a simplifed, copyable example of `dict_sim_score`

Comment: When you say *"it doesn't appear to be achieving my goal"* could you be more specific?

Comment: I've provided a dict that can be used to make the heatmap.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would do this using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) to unstack the data, followed by [`seaborn`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) to plot the results. Here is an example using the dictionary you provided:

```
import pandas as pd
ser = pd.Series(list(dict_sim_scores.values()),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(dict_sim_scores.keys()))
df = ser.unstack().fillna(0)
df.shape
# (10, 27)
```

Now use the `seaborn` heatmap function to plot the results:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was going for.

Comment: Literally the most relatable answer to the questions I have ever browsed on SO. +1